# Can I use list data sets to deep learning traning?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

My deep learning model will use some supervised learning datas
Data will loaded in .npz(numpy arrays) files, each files will have the 30 array list datas. 
I have to traning model that using these data sets
It will be loaded when I call it in python function. Then, model will be starting training this data sets.
And the correlation between these data sets is important.

This is the subject of this question.
I will load the entire file in the folder. Then the model will continue learning until data loading is complete.
So, Can I use this data set files in training? 
And how to training my model..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you should be able to convert certain data structures to tensors such as numpy arrays.

```
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a) # np array to tensor
```

This is a simple article for beginners if that helps with training:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/create-a-neural-network-in-pytorch-and-make-your-life-simpler-ec5367895199